# Firebase database, why is the print line which is after the firebase code gets printed before?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

when button is pressed the codes below executes. and in the console this gets printed.

1. 3
2. 2

Current Patient ID: 2

New Patient ID: 3

as you can obviously see the `generateID()` gets triggered before `print("2. \(patient.id)")` therefore it should print in console like below:

1. 3

Current Patient ID: 2

New Patient ID: 3

2. 3

what is wrong?
I am new and appreciate any help.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let patientDatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("Patients")

    print("1. \(patient.id)") // patient.id is naturally set to 3.

    patient.id = "2"

    patientDatabaseReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for childSnap in  snapshot.children {
            guard let childSnapshot = childSnap as? DataSnapshot else {
                continue
            }

            if childSnapshot.key == self.patient.id {
                self.generateID() // I have made sure that this line gets executed.
            }

        }
    })

print("2. \(patient.id)")

}
```

//

```
func generateID() {

    let numberOfPatientsReference = Database.database().reference(withPath: "NumberOfPatients")
    numberOfPatientsReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if !snapshot.exists() {
            return
        }

        self.patient.id = "\(snapshot.value!)"

        print("Current Patient ID: \(self.patient.id)")

        var intPatientID = Int(self.patient.id)!
        intPatientID += 1
        self.patient.id = "\(intPatientID)"

        print("New Patient ID: \(self.patient.id)")

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is asynchronous. This means that print line will happen while the observe block talks to the network.  If you put the print statement in the observe block of code it will work the way you were expecting it to.